# how to convert a 3d array representing timeseries data for tensorflowlite....note the model works for python and now porting to swift

Tags: ios, swift, time-series, lstm, tensorflow-lite

I created a model in python tensorflow and then converted the model to a tensorflowlite model.  I tested this "lite" model in python with the following code and it works:

```
for s in range(X_new.shape[0]):
    m=np.float32(X_new[s])
    input_data=m.reshape(1,140,6)
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

    interpreter.invoke()
    tflite_results = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

---

Note the model is for a timeseries and the X_new shape is (number of samples, lag, features).  I'm passing it into the regular model and for some reason I had to individually handle it as one row at a time (1,140,6) for the lite....

My issue is that I'm now trying to have the model work on IOS (Swift).  I had to create an 3 dimensional array of the data in Swift

```
[[[Float]]]
```

and I am now at the point of trying to create the tensor and invoke.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find the same API for Swift so looking at other RNN code (the Bert example) I came across this approach

```
let inputIdsData = Data(copyingBufferOf: features.inputIds)
let inputMaskData = Data(copyingBufferOf: features.inputMask)
let segmentIdsData = Data(copyingBufferOf: features.segmentIds)

// Assign input `Data` to the `interpreter`.
try interpreter.copy(inputIdsData, toInputAt: 0)
try interpreter.copy(inputMaskData, toInputAt: 1)
try interpreter.copy(segmentIdsData, toInputAt: 2)

// Run inference by invoking the `Interpreter`.
os_log("[BertQAHandler] Runing inference..")
try interpreter.invoke()
```

Assuming this is the "right" approach (which it may not be) I'm struggling on how get the line
interpreter.copy
to compile.  First it needs a Data object and when I try to create a Data object from a my 3d array  it gave me an error
"No exact matches in call to initializer".  I tried flattening the 3d object using .joined() but then the error became

```
"Initializer 'init(_:)' requires the types 'FlattenSequence<[[Float]]>.Element' (aka 'Float') and 'UInt8' be equivalent"
```

At this point I'm at a loss.  I would naively assume that flattening was not required as I didn't have to do anything in particular for python.  I suspect my issue is how to create the tensor in swift (the equivalent of what I was able to do with set_tensor in python) but can't seem to find the correct way to create a Data object.

Any suggestions on the right approach and examples of how to invoke tensorflow lite model with a 3 dimensional data set?